# Filters with two properties in extjs

Tags: extjs

I need to create a filter that has two properties or operators.
I need to filter the Type AND the Number to put in combobox. The data are shown in the same table in the database. In this filter below I can just filter the number, it ignores the type.

Does anyone know if there is any way to do? Thanks.

```
filters: [
        {
            property: 'type',
            operator: '=',
            value: 'recorder'
        },
        {
            property: 'number',
            operator: '=',
            value: '{number.value}'
        }
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the type of data you want to filter, it's hard to say why the type fiilter is not working. On a first glance, the filter config looks fine.

However, if the filter config won't work for any reason, you can also pass in a function for filtering:

```
filters: [
    function(item) {
        return item.get('type') == 'recorder';
    },
    {
        property: 'number',
        operator: '=',
        value: '{number.value}'
    }
]
```

Using a function also has the advantage, that you can set a break point and check which value is actually validated.